# How to play a mp3 stream integrated into iPod on iOS

Tags: ios, stream, mp3

I have a standard mp3 stream that is delivered through http. I use the approach used in this example project:

https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer/

Basically it uses the approach described in Apples ["Audio Stream Reference"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioStreamReference/Reference/reference.html). If I set `UIBackgroundModes` to `audio` iOS plays the sound if the app is in the background.

But how can I make the iPod controls in the taskbar work? How can I integrate properly with iPod on iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controls in the taskbar fire remote-control events (for example like controls that are integrated into the head phones). If you follow the instructions described in Apples documentation [Remote Control of Multimedia](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/RemoteControl/RemoteControl.html) and set `UIBackgroundModes` to `audio`, then everything behaves as expected: If the app is suspended the sound continues to play, you app icon appears in the iPod menu in the taskbar and the buttons trigger events.